# Kubernetes inter-pod port exhaustion

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core, reverse-proxy

I have a pod with 3 containers.

1. .Net core REST microservice
2. .Net core Reverse Proxy
3. Istio proxy

Traffic comes into the Reverse Proxy, is validated, and then proxied onto the microservice. This is my most heavily used service and it starts to have this error after running for about a day.

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (99): Cannot assign requested address
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
```

Restarting the pod is my only fix right now. I've goofed around looking at tcp statistics on the nodes, but it doesn't make sense that that would be the issue as killing the pod and restarting makes the problem go away.

I've also messed around with the httpclient available in .net core using the best practices with no change.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like two services trying to bind the same port: the last one can't. Containers from a Pod would share the same netnamespace. Though I'm not sure it makes sense, would your application bind to new addresses, during runtime?!

Comment: I believe that if it were 2 services attempting to bind to the same port, I'd get some immediate failures. We have many other microservices that run in a similar manner, and I only see the issue on this one after a time of heavy load. All inter-pod communication can be done using localhost (but your apps do need to be running on different ports).

Comment: Is it possible the reverse-proxy code is failing to close connections when a request finishes?  There are a couple of resources it's possible to exhaust (file descriptors, TCP ports) and if you start getting errors like this, but only after a day of sustained traffic, and restarting helps, that sort of sounds like a resource leak.

Comment: I'll educate myself on file descriptors and take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further gathering of clues, I learned that these errors only show up while our REST microservice restarts (due to a memory leak). The error makes sense in context and I overestimated the severity of the issue.